# jQuery .prop() checked not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following function, when i check a checkbox 'chx', debugger is telling me 'name' is undefined. I dont see what is the error here:

```
<script>
   function nameF() {
       $('#chx').prop('checked') ? $('div').slideDown() : $('div').slideUp();
   }
</script>
```

checkbox:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chx" runat="server" Text="Text" onchange="nameF('div')" />
```

Edit:

Looks like none of the answers is showing the div,

```
   function medicalProblems(Medfurtherdetails) {
                  $('#chxMedicalVision').prop('checked') ? $(Medfurtherdetails).show() : $(Medfurtherdetails).hide();
   }
```

checkbox:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chxMedicalVision" runat="server" Text="Vision" onchange="medicalProblems('Medfurtherdetails')" />
```

the div:

```
    <div id="Medfurtherdetails" style="display:none"></div>
```

Now this is workign altough not hiding the div when nothing is checked:

```
   function medicalProblems(thediv) {
       if ($("#chxMedicalVision").prop('checked') || $("#chxMedicalHearing").prop('checked') || $("#chxMedicalSpeech").prop('checked'))
       {
        $("#" + thediv).slideUp();
      }
      else
    {
        $("#" + thediv).slideDown();
    }
}
```

Comment: You send a parameter in a fucntion without a parameter:)

Comment: $('#chx').is (':checked')?

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
$('#chx').prop('checked') ? $(element).slideDown() : $(element).slideUp();
```

to

```
$(this).prop('checked') ? $(element).slideDown() : $(element).slideUp();
```

and remove the 'div' parameter as mentioned in other answers.

Answer (score -1):

```
<script>
   function nameF(x) {
   $('#chx').prop('checked') ? $('div').slideDown() : $('div').slideUp();
  }
</script>

<asp:CheckBox ID="chx" runat="server" Text="Text" onchange="nameF('div')" />
```

if you want to pass a parameter there should be a variable that will hold in it.

Answer (score -1):

Either remove `'div'` from this

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chx" runat="server" Text="Text" onchange="nameF('div')" />
```

which should be like this

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chx" runat="server" Text="Text" onchange="nameF()" />
```

**OR**

do something like this

```
<script>
   function nameF(mydiv) {
       $('#chx').prop('checked') ? $('#'+mydiv).slideDown() : $('#'+mydiv).slideUp();
   }
</script>
```

Comment: didn't get you.. when you add `style="display:none"` it hides your div.

Comment: yes. Default there is no need to show the div. I am using toggle in other place, because in this case there are some checkboxes and toggle is not working the way i intend to.